# How to run Javascript in newly opened window?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following code.

```
window.open(url, windowName, "height=500,width=500") 
// This will open a new window with the url.

myFunction();
// Run this function on the newly opened window instead of
// the old one because I need to find a link on the new page.
```

Right now, myFunction() is getting stuck on the old window.

Update: The new url is the another domain.

Comment: you can't. That would allow you to run javascript on arbitrary pages without the user knowing, which means you could do some very malicious things. If you are the owner of the `url` you are opening, then you can provide a mechanism on that page to read javascript from the URL parameters if you want, and execute that, but I wouldn't recommend that either.

Comment: @Christian - This is not true for the urls from same domain.

Comment: Zip is trying to find a link on the new page. I doubt he would go through this hoop if he was in control of the new page (i.e., it's not on his domain).

Answer (score -1):

Put your `myFunction()` in the script of the new window.

Then set the `onLoad` event of that window to run it.

You can get reference to your caller window's document from the new window by:

```
window.opener.document
```

There you go with enough links to do pretty much anything.

Update:

Your new window should be from the same domain. Otherwise its against the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) of the browser.

Please see this question:

[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: I'm not the one who down voted, but I agree that this most likely doesn't answer the questions. Zip is trying to find a link on the new page. I doubt he would go through this hoop if he was in control of the new page.

Comment: He added that part to the question when I first talked about it in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You have several options:

1. edit the source code for the webpage stored at `url` to include your own custom code that you want to run when the webpage opens. If you only want this code to run when the webpage opens from your popup, you could name the url something like "webpage.html?run_custom_code", then in webpage.html have javascript that only runs if `window.location.href.indexOf('run_custom_code') > 0`
2. you can open a webpage that's sole purpose is to run javascript: `window.open('javascript:alert()');` although based on your edit this does not seem useful to you.
3. Use another language like PHP, where you can fetch the contents of another webpage with something like `$html = file_get_contents($url);`
4. perform an [ajax request](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to the other url (if it resides on the same domain) and scrape the results to find your link.